# Vue.js multiple filters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to filter some content rendered with Vue.js , but only the first filter is working, the size filter.

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#full_area",
    data: {
        projects: <?php print json_encode($postsa);?>,
        selectedSize: "All",
        selectedPlatform: "All"
    },
    computed: {
        filteredProjects: function () {
            var vm = this;
            var size = vm.selectedSize;
            var platform = vm.selectedPlatform;

            if (size === "All") {
                return vm.projects;
            } else if (size != "All") {
                return vm.projects.filter(function (project) {
                    return project.size === size;
                });
            }
            if (platform === "All") {
                return vm.projects;
            } else if (platform != "All") {
                return vm.projects.filter(function (project) {
                    return project.platform === platform;
                });
            }


        }
    }
});


        <div class="filter">

            <select name="selectedSize" v-model="selectedSize">
                <option value="All">Website Size</option>
                <option>1 Page</option>
       ...
                <option>10+ Page</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="filter">

            <select name="selectedPlatform" v-model="selectedPlatform">
                <option value="All">CMS Platform</option>
                <option>Wordpress</option>
        .....
            </select>
        </div>
```

I have tried several thing playing with the if`s and else, but no luck. Have any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: You are `return`-ing. Which ends the execution of the function. If you want to return the result of multiple filters, you have to hold the results of the previous filter in the result, filter by all subsequent filters and at the end return the final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A less verbose way of doing it:

```js
    computed: {
        filteredProjects: function () {
            const size = this.selectedSize,
              platform = this.selectedPlatform;
            return this.projects
              .filter(p => size === 'All' || p.size === size)
              .filter(p => platform === 'All' || p.platform === platform)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter by size first, and then platform. In your current code, the return statements handling the filter by size functionality make the code after it unreachable.

Try something like this:

```
    filteredProjects: function () {
        var vm = this;
        var size = vm.selectedSize;
        var platform = vm.selectedPlatform;
        var filteredProjects;

        // first, filter by size, saving the results to
        // the variable filteredProjects
        if (size === "All") {
            filteredProjects = vm.projects;
        } else {
            filteredProjects = vm.projects.filter(function (project) {
                return project.size === size;
            });
        }

        // then, continue filtering `filteredProjects`, using the platform
        if (platform === "All") {
            filteredProjects = filteredProjects;
        } else {
            filteredProjects = filteredProjects.filter(function (project) {
                return project.platform === platform;
            });
        }
        return filteredProjects

    }
```

I also change the `else if` statements to be simply `else`. Variables can either be equal to `All` or not - no need to spell out the alternative explicitly.